# Checkbox look in Opera

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have page with dark background. In IE, Firefox, Chrome and Safari my checkboxes looks like this:
[image]

But Opera displays checkboxes like this:

[image]

So user cannot see if he checked the checkbox, because the tick (check-mark) is black as well.

Here is part of my css:

```
body {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: #07080A;
    background-image: url('images/bg.jpg');
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 0 none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: auto auto;
    width: 1000px;
}

input, textarea {
    width: 300px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #323232;
    border: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding: 8px 0px 8px 10px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]{
    background: transparent;
    width: 30px;
}
```

How can I change that? I would like to have appearance of checkbox the same in Opera and other browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to override your first style using:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    background: inherit;
    width: 30px;
}
```

This will give the checkbox the background of its parent. Depending on the order of your rules and other rules, you might need to use `inherit !important`.

Answer (score 1):

In Opera, the background property applies to the background inside the checkbox not the background outside of the checkbox.  I believe what you're trying to fix is some of the issues that you can [find on this page about how checkboxes are styled](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/checkbox/).

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type="checkbox"]{
    backgorund: #fff;
    width: 30px;
}
```

Does that not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a typo in your input[type="checkbox"] line.

Second, according to [this](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/form_controls/checkboxes/) you could explicitly set the checkbox background to be white.  This works in Opera.